# Unable to deserialize a custom Serde using Kafka-Streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create a simple topology to upperCase a `person` entity using Kafka-streams.

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)
```

My custom Serializer and Deserializer are like this:

```
    class KafkaBytesSerializer[T] extends Serializer[T] {
      override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit = 0

      override def serialize(topic: String, data: T): Array[Byte] = {
        val stream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
        oos.writeObject(data)
        oos.close()
        stream.toByteArray
      }
      override def close(): Unit = 0
    }

class KafkaBytesDeserializer[T] extends Deserializer[T]{
  override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit = 0

  override def deserialize(topic: String, data: Array[Byte]): T = {
    val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
    val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[T]
    objIn.close
    obj
  }

  override def close(): Unit = 0
}
```

The main calling code of the streaming app is this:

```
val personSerde: Serde[Person] = 
 Serdes.serdeFrom(new KafkaBytesSerializer[Person], new KafkaBytesDeserializer[Person])

val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
    builder
.stream[String, Person](INPUT_TOPIC)(Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), personSerde))
.map[String, Person]((k,p) => (k, Person(p.id, p.name.toUpperCase(), p.age)))
.peek((k, p) => println("Key" + k + " Person: " + p))
.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC)(Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), personSerde))
```

When I run the application, I am getting the class cast exception:

```
[MainApp-consumer-group-b45b436d-1412-494b-9733-f75a61c9b9e3-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [MainApp-consumer-group-b45b436d-1412-494b-9733-f75a61c9b9e3-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following error during processing:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to models.Person
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.FunctionsCompatConversions$ValueMapperFromFunction$$anon$6.apply(FunctionsCompatConversions.scala:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$withKey$1(AbstractStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:40)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
```

I suspect something is going wrong at the deserialization level, but not sure why?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure, that is whole code? It looks like you call in your code `KStream::mapValues`?

Comment: Thanks, @wardziniak! fixed the typo and updated the code.

Comment: Are you sure that is whole code? It looks ok. Could you add more stack trace and imports?

Comment: @wardziniak I have added the commit here https://github.com/surysharma/kafka-streams-tinker/commit/6fa9d2423b54377eee99d803376965ab89011d9e hope this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with you ProducerApp. You set `value.serializer` to `com.thebigscale.serdes.PersonSerializer` and then try to send array of bytes. You shouldn't serialize you POJO. Kafka Serializer will do it for you - just sent Person object instance.

Below I've fixed your code with comments

```scala
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "com.thebigscale.serdes.PersonSerializer")

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, Person](props) // <-- Instead BYTE_ARRAY -> Person

val person = new Person(4, "user4", 27)
//val personSerializer = new KafkaBytesSerializer[Person]() // remove
//val bytePerson: BYTE_ARRAY = personSerializer.serialize("", person) // remove

val record = new ProducerRecord[String, Person](KafkaConf.INPUT_TOPIC, "key1", person) // instead BYTE_ARRAY -> Person, bytePerson -> person
producer.send(record, new Callback {
  override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
    if (exception != null ) {
      println("Exception thrown by producer: " + exception)
    } else {
      println("Record sent successfully: " + metadata)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the wrong side of the bridge :-) I have accepted your answer.